# Connecting to Amazon ElastiCache using Java Redis client (Lettuce)

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, redis

. . it is possible to connect to Amazon Elastic Cache from my local machine with a java redis client (lettuce) ?

I have defined Inbound rules in the Security Group to TCP port 6379 and SSH port 22 to any IP address.

my connecting code is:

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient("CacheCluster Endpoint", 6379);

RedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();

connection.set("key", "Hello, Redis!");

connection.close();
redisClient.shutdown();
```

I run this java and I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to mycachecluster.b4ujee.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com/172.31.34.211:6379
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.AbstractRedisClient.initializeChannel(AbstractRedisClient.java:214)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient.connectAsync(RedisClient.java:322)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient.connectAsync(RedisClient.java:303)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:259)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:238)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:222)
    at project1.JavaRedis.main(JavaRedis.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: mycachecluster.b4ujee.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com/172.31.34.211:6379
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

so my question is: What am I doing so wrong ? have I to use the ClusterRedis EndPoint or EC2 DNS to stablished the connection ?

help please !!!

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't connect to it because it doesn't have a public IP. The DNS name resolves into a private IP, 172.31.34.211, which can only be accessed from your AWS VPC. 
Also, for connecting you need to use the DNS, not the IP, because the IP of the node might change.
If you need to develop locally with Redis, you can easily install one instance on your local machine.

Comment: Then ... What have I to do if I want to create a Web Service that connect to my aws redis cluster ?

Comment: You host your web service on AWS on a machine with public IP or using an Elastic Load Balancer and you can call that directly from anywhere, including your local machine.

Comment: If I use a  Load Balancer on AWS I can access to my Web Service from my local machine . . . but in order to my Web Service be able to connect to my Redis Cluster instance, it has to be always deployed in the EC2 Instance of amazon . . .is that right ?

Comment: yes, and you need to have your web service part of the same AWS VPC as your elasticache redis instance so you can connect to it

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, if you still want to connect from your local to AWS ElastiCache (redis) without hosting your web service in AWS, is through a VPN.

We are using https://pritunl.com for this, it is very easy to configure and use.